# If an element is already visible how do I stop it from toggling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a hover state and onclick state on a page. I also have a toggle on the hover state. If the user has already onclicked an element, how do I stop that element toggling again if the hover event re-occurs?

```
$("#ex").hover(function() {

 $("#prod").toggle(300).delay(1000);
 $("#test").toggle(300).delay(1000);
 $("#dev").toggle(300).delay(1000);

});

$("#prod").click(function() {
 $("#prod").unbind("mouseenter mouseleave");
 $("#prod").finish();
 $("#prod").show();
});

$("#test").click(function() {
 $("#test").unbind("mouseenter mouseleave");
 $("#test").finish();
 $("#test").show();
});

$("#dev").click(function() {
 $("#dev").unbind("mouseenter mouseleave");
 $("#dev").finish();
 $("#dev").show();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`.is(":visible")`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector and check if it is visible, if so, don't toggle.

```
$("#ex").hover(function() {
  if (!$("#prod").is(":visible")) $("#prod").toggle(300).delay(1000);
  if (!$("#test").is(":visible")) $("#test").toggle(300).delay(1000);
  if (!$("#dev").is(":visible")) $("#dev").toggle(300).delay(1000);
});
```